# Oracle "into" clause in Oracle version below 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have pl/sql anonymous block like below

```
declare
  v_count pls_integer := 0;
begin
  select count(1) from product_component_version
    into v_count
   where product like '%Enterprise%';
  if v_count = 0 then
    raise program_error;
  end if;
exception
  when program_error then
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'This is valid for Oracle Enterprise Edition         only!');
end;
```

When I try to execute the above,I am getting the below error

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Which is nothing but for "into v_count" statement.

As per my understanding the syntax is wrong and when I changed that statemnt like below it is working fine.

```
select count(1) into v_count
  from product_component_version
 where product like '%Enterprise%';
```

I have tested this in "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit".

But the original script is available in all our older versions of our product.
I would like to know the syntax in original script is supported in older oracle versions?
Or can you please let me know any information on this which can answer my confusion?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: I don't think the first syntax was *ever* supported.

Comment: "script is available"? Its not stored in db, so I assume this non-working code sits in a file somewhere (and is never used).  How do you know this code is being used at all (no matter what version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a test block:

```
declare
    x dual.dummy%type;
begin
    select dummy from dual into x;
end;
/
```

In Oracle 9iR2 (9.2.0.8 on Solaris), 10gR2 (10.2.0.5 on Solaris) and 11gR2 (11.2.0.3 on Linux) I get exactly the same error:

```
    select dummy from dual into x;
                           *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 28:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I don't believe it has ever been supported the way you had it, though I don't have an 8i or earlier database to test against.

You said 'the original script is available in all our older versions of our product', but would it actually ever have been run, and if so can you identify an exact version it didn't raise an error against?

Comment: Not related to the original question, why not use `%ROWTYPE` and a `select *`? It's faster to type

Comment: @Plouf - no particular reason; habit from avoiding `select *` perhaps, and the OP selecting a single value rather than a row; and it makes no difference to the effect. Does thinking about saving 6 keypresses (if you count `shift-8` to get `*` as one) qualify as premature optimisation? *8-)

Comment: Could be. :-) But I'd rather put it as an habit. And +1 for the premature which is too often forgot when quoting

Comment: @Plouf faster to type and but incomplete When the `where` clause finds no matches, your version will throw `ORA-01403, no data found`. So you need to add an `exception when no_data_found then raise_application_error...`. Or add a comment letting who ever is using this script know what "no data found" really means.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - so would my version, though if `dual` throws that then there are bigger problems. This really wasn't meant to be production-ready *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole, I mistook which query you and Plouf were talking about changing. Now I feel silly.

Answer (score 2):

At least not from 8i onwards:
http://www.oracle.com/pls/tahiti/tahiti.tabbed?section=49135

Answer (score 0):

Even i don't thing so about select dummy from dual into x;

try this:

```
declare
  v_count pls_integer := 0;
begin
  select count(1) into v_count from product_component_version

   where product like '%Enterprise%';
  if v_count = 0 then
    raise program_error;
  end if;
exception
  when program_error then
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'This is valid for Oracle Enterprise Edition         only!');
end;
```

Comment: The question shows the valid syntax too, so that isn't the issue; it's whether (and how) the invalid syntax has ever worked.